# Tween Blur A Movie Clip Using AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, blur

I am trying to tween a movie clip called "SmartBg" to blur from zero to 8% on trigger of a mouse click event on another movieclip.

How do I go about achieving that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using the GTween library for it: http://www.gskinner.com/libraries/gtween/

Actually, they even have an example about twenning blur of a clip: http://www.gskinner.com/libraries/gtween/demos/GTweenSimpleSequencing.swf

Comment: That's is a nice tool, thanks for it. Will have to familiarize myself with it. But how do I go about setting it up for use? - save me time of having to joggle tru their documentation.